# Will Spring 3.5 abandon IoC or XML Bean Configurations?

Tags: spring, annotations, inversion-of-control

I have heard that Spring - after establishing annotations with version 2 - might be abandoning IoC and XML bean definitions altogether in Spring version 3.5.

Is that a known fact or nonsense?

**update**

My colleague is pretty sure he was told by a spring instructor that
as of Spring 3.5 annotation style progamming would be focused on exclusively.
(If that would mean desupporting the older approaches I do not know)

Since that information is 1-2 years old it might be outdated allready though.

*(changed Spring v4 to v3.5 with this edit)*

Comment: I think even if they want to favor one way over another, they will still support all ways for backward compatiblity. There are way too many applications relying on that.

Comment: Where did you hear this? Do you have a source?

Comment: Since I am not confident in the source of my source and some design dessions might rely on this information I was asking about it here. I will check with my colleague about his source again, but it might have been mentioned in some way or another at a spring training course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say it's nonsense (though I've never heard any plans about spring 4)

- IoC is a concept behind spring, related to "dependency injection", so that's perhaps a term misunderstanding
- XML - frameworks like CDI that don't use XML have plugins that enable XML configuration because in some scenarios it is the better approach. For example for establishing configurations in the project. I don't think spring will abandon such a rich xml support (and break backward compatibility completely)

Comment: I was aiming at IoC in the context of configuring Beans via XML definitions. Im still not really versed in annotation based spring and don't have the hang of implementing the IoC pattern with annotations, so I thought of annotations as an antonym to XML based configuration.